# Indirect measurement of the distributions

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that there is a field where cabbages grow. We have weighed all the cabbages in spring and got Gaussian distribution of weights. The same we did in autumn and got another Gaussian distribution. The question is how to get distribution of growth rates (times over the summer) if cabbages are not numbered? Will it be Gaussian or not?

Comment: Is this a question about cabbages or statistics? Even if it's about statistics, I don't think this is answerable. On other grounds, I wouldn't expect Gaussians to remain Gaussians because growth isn't like that; there is a usually a skewed distribution of growth rates, but I don't think that is deducible from what you have here. In this case, some cabbages might even lose weight (evaporation, pest damage, disease, death).

Comment: Without following individual cabbages any assumptions you'd have to make to get an answer would be very strong ones.  Do small cabbages continue as the runts of the litter or do they put on a spurt to catch up with the big ones that have already grown up?